# sliding UITableView over image

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

The user first sees an image at the top of the page; the rest of the page is a UITableView directly below the image.

When the user slides up on the table, I'd like to slide the entire UITableView up so that it covers the image, and then start scrolling the table cells. Sliding down (once the first cell is at the top) the UITableView would then slide down to reveal the image again.

This is similar to what the Crackle app (and other apps) do. What is a good / elegant way to do this?

Comment: I didn't quiet understand it, but it seems like you can add the imageView as your first cell.

Comment: @AbinGeorge: While the table view is sliding up, I want it to slowly cover the image, which remains in place (but underneath the table view). They are two distinct elements.

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of TableView by setting its frame,
self.tableView.frame=self.view.frame in
-scrollViewWillBeginDragging:

Answer (score 0):

There are undoubtedly several ways to accomplish this. On way involves having that image inside the first cell, which would be different than the other cells with your data. When you scroll, the position of that image in the cell would be moved down, which would make it appear that the image is being covered by the cell below. The code below shows how to do this (I modified this from another project that had alternating rows that appeared to float over fixed images).

```
@interface TableController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *theData;
@end

@implementation TableController 


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.theData = @[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight",@"Nine",@"Black",@"Brown",@"Red",@"Orange",@"Yellow",@"Green",@"Blue"];
}



-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    RDCell *topCell = (RDCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    [topCell updateImageViewWithOffset:scrollView.contentOffset.y];
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.theData.count + 1;
}



-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat height = (indexPath.row == 0)? 140 : 44;
    return height;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        RDCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ImageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }else{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = self.theData[indexPath.row - 1];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

The code in the custom cell was just this one method,

```
-(void)updateImageViewWithOffset:(CGFloat) offset {
    CGFloat cellY = self.frame.origin.y;
    self.topCon.constant = offset - cellY;
}
```

topCon is an IBOutlet to an NSLayoutConstraint, between the top of the cell and the top of the image view in the cell -- it's important the the image view have constraints to the top and sides of the cell, and a height constraint (equal to the height of the cell), but no constraint to the bottom of the cell. If you want to see if this approach gives you the look you want, you can download the sample project from here, http://jmp.sh/zOVz6Ev.